# How to Dim a getElementsBy* result

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing some internet searching from VBA, and at one point I have the line

```
Set valueResult = currPage.getElementById("rg_s").getElementsByTagName("IMG")
```

where `currPage` is declared as an `HTMLDocument`

and I'm wondering how to `Dim` `valueResult` to achieve:

1. IntelliSense (vba's autocomplete) results
2. Better execution times (by using a specific rather than default `Variant` type)

When I look at the Locals window, I'm told that `Set` gives it the 
 `DispHTMLElementCollection` type, but that's not an option when I `Dim`. I've [read](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/5918/completely-undocumented-dom-class-disphtmlelementcollection/3) that `getElementsBy*` actually returns a [`Node List`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-536297177) as opposed to an array, so I've been trying to follow that avenue, but can't find anything VBA specific.

**So how should I declare it?** - at the moment I've just got `Dim valueResult As Object` but that's hardly better than `Variant` and doesn't give IntelliSense prompts.

*NB. I have Microsoft HTML Object Library ticked*

Comment: does `HTMLDivElement` work?

Comment: use `TypeName` in the immediate window, when in this kind of difficulty, and the locals window is also extremely useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be an `IHTMLElementCollection` type.

```
Dim valueResult As IHTMLElementCollection

'// your code here

Set valueResult = currPage.getElementById("rg_s").getElementsByTagName("IMG")
```

The `getElementsByTagName()` method will return a `Collection` because there are potentially multiple matches. The `getElementById()` method will return an element, so `IHTMLElement`

---

quick example:

```
Sub test()

Dim col As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim item As IHTMLElement

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "http://www.google.co.uk"

While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Set col = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each i In col
    Set item = i
    Debug.Print item.outerText
Next

IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- The most important is to add references:

  - Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
  - Microsoft HTML Object Library

*Early* and *late binding* has its advantages and disadvantages, but if you want to have the support of intellisense then the reference to type library will be necessary. When declaring as `Object` no intellisense will be available because during design time Visual Basic runtime can't know what kind of reference the variable will contain. That will be known first at runtime.

[image]

Then this code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

can be replaced by code like this:

```
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

Without reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`  the declarations like `Dim col As IHTMLElementCollection` *will not compile*.

Then the `Object Browser` is your friend:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Without this references the declarations like Dim col As IHTMLElementCollection will not compile.` - you _only_ need the HTML object library for that to compile, Internet controls isn't needed. In a live environment it's actually better to use late binding for things such as IE automation.

Comment: +1 For reference to object browser. Most of the steps in this answer were covered to an exten in my question, but I appreciate that the object browser can provide the answer if I have the same sort of question in the future. @MacroMan I'm interested, what do you mean by the term *'late bindings'*?

Comment: @Greedo When you use `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` you are _late_ binding. This means you're creating the object without actually setting a reference to it's library beforehand. If you use `Dim IE As New InternetExplorer` then you have a reference set to that library and this is called _early_ binding. [More information here](http://excelmatters.com/2013/09/23/vba-references-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/)