# Late binding UDFs for access across workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I made a UDF in excel which I want to access from all of my excel projects. To do this I put it in a module of `PERSONAL.XLSB` and invoke with `=PERSONAL.XLSB!MYFUNC(Arg1, Arg2...)`

However I get the error `User-defined type not defined`. This is, if I understand correctly (and I may not!), because my project uses early binding and requires a Library reference to *Microsoft Internet Controls*. Solution according to [this site](http://excelmatters.com/2013/09/23/vba-references-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/) is to use late binding by first declaring all the variables as `Object`s and then setting them in some way that I'm not entirely sure about

#### Some code

Here's my code, stripped of everything except for the `Dim`s and `Set`s that reference the internet controls:

```
Public Function GOOGLE_COUNT_latebound(searchTerm As String, xRes As Long, yRes As Long, Optional timeout As Long = 10, Optional arrayIndex As Long = 1) As Variant

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim currPage As HTMLDocument
    Dim valueResult As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Set currPage = objIE.document
    Dim myDiv As HTMLDivElement: Set myDiv = currPage.getElementById("fbar")
    Dim elemRect As IHTMLRect: Set elemRect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect
    Set valueResult = currPage.getElementById("rg_s").getElementsByTagName("IMG")
    objIE.Quit
    
End Function
```

Now to late bind `objIE` I simply write

```
Dim objIE as object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")'(but why .Application I'm still not sure about?)
```

And then for all of the `HTMLDocument` and `HTMLDivElement` or anything else which is a subset* of objIE: The linked page makes me think I should declare the variable type as a constant (see below)

*(by "subset" I mean *set relative* to objIE. Like the `HTMLDocument` is `set` as a `objIE.document` or the `HTMLDivElement` is set as a `objIE.document.getElementById("fbar")`. See, all relative to the application `objIE` - I don't know what the general term for these variables would be).

```
Const HTMLDocument As Long = 0
```

And then create items as a from my objIE object using the declared type:

```
Dim currPage As Object
Set currPage = objIE.CreateItem("HTMLDocument")
```

Is this correct? What is the meaning of the `Const` declaration, and do I always just declare a number like that or does it change with data type? How do I know what to set it to?

Perhaps there's a better way of getting my UDF publically accessible, maybe this has nothing to do with binding. These are all concepts I'm very new to and am yet to find instructions I can follow!

Comment: `Dim currPage As Object: Set currPage = objIE.document` would still work as a late binding

Comment: At what line did you got the error? If you have added the references to `MS HTML Object Library` and to `MS Internet Controls` in your PERSONAL Workbook, it should work.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx#properties should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your code adapted to use late binding

```
Public Function GOOGLE_COUNT_latebound(searchTerm As String, xRes As Long, yRes As Long, Optional timeout As Long = 10, Optional arrayIndex As Long = 1) As Variant

    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim currPage As Object
    Dim valueResult As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    Set currPage = objIE.document
    Dim myDiv As Object: Set myDiv = currPage.getElementById("fbar")
    Dim elemRect As Object: Set elemRect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect
    Set valueResult = currPage.getElementById("rg_s").getElementsByTagName("IMG")
    objIE.Quit

End Function
```

Comment: I see, simply replace object specific names with `Object` in my `dim`. Then what is the meaning of declairing a `const` (see the linked page in my question)? Could you not just use `Set oItem = oAPP.CreateItem(olMailItem)` on its own in that situation?

Comment: olMailItem is a constant that is defined when you add the reference to outlook. If you don't reference outlook, this constant is not defined, hence the need to define it explicitely. You could also use the value of the constant in the instruction eg `oAPP.CreateItem(0)` please also note that by default a variable is initialized to 0, so by chance ´oAPP.createItem(olMailItem)` will work as well.

Comment: To find the value of constants I find the easiest way is to open the application in question (in your comment above it would be Outlook), open the VBE and type `?olMailItem` in the immediate window - it will return 0.

Comment: I see, constants are not accessible without the reference. Also the code all works except for `Dim elemRect As Object: Set elemRect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRec` - why might this be? It is an IHTML object in my early bound code, [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219328(v=office.11).aspx) says IHTML objects refer to page elements which don't have a corresponding object, so maybe that's the cause; `Dim`ing `elemRect` as an unspecified object is not allowed?

Comment: See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43066307/6609896) about this issue